# Linq to entities contains with dynamic field and int32

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, dynamic-programming

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do all three of the following in a single call:

1. Use the .Contains method to perform a "LIKE" operation on my SQL Server
2. Convert the value from an Int32 to string so that I can do a .Contains on it
3. Allow the user to pass in a custom field name, so using something like SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)d.ID).Contains(idSearch) won't work.  I have no idea what column I'll be checking.

Preferably, I'd like to do something like this:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Like<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string fieldName, object value)
    {
        ... Code here
    }
}
```

I think I need to use an Expression Tree to handle this, but I'm having a really hard time finding any tutorials on how to use Dynamic Linq/expression trees.  Any ideas or links to help me out here would be appreciated.  Or, if anybody has a library that already does this, that'd even be better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the extension method I wrote that performs a LIKE on an Int32:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
  public static IQueryable<T> Like<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, object value)
  {
      IQueryable<T> returnQuery = null;
      switch (value.GetType().ToString())
      {
          case "System.String":
              returnQuery = source.Where(LikeLambdaString<T>(propertyName, value.ToString()));
              break;
          default:
              returnQuery = source.Where(LikeLambdaDouble<T>(propertyName, Convert.ToDouble(value)));
              break;        
      }

      return returnQuery;
  }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> LikeLambdaString<T>(string propertyName, string value)
  {
      var linqParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), propertyName);
      var linqProp = GetProperty<T>(linqParam, propertyName);

      var containsFunc = Expression.Call(linqProp,
          typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
          new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(value) });

      return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsFunc,
              new ParameterExpression[] { linqParam });
  }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> LikeLambdaDouble<T>(string propertyName, double? value)
  {
      string stringValue = (value == null) ? string.Empty : value.ToString();
      var linqParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), propertyName);
      var linqProp = GetProperty<T>(linqParam, propertyName);

      var stringConvertMethodInfo =
          typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethod("StringConvert", new Type[] { typeof(double?) });

      var stringContainsMethodInfo =
          typeof(String).GetMethod("Contains");

      return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
          Expression.Call(Expression.Call(
                  stringConvertMethodInfo,
                  Expression.Convert(
                      linqProp,
                      typeof(double?))),
              stringContainsMethodInfo,
              Expression.Constant(stringValue)),
          linqParam);
  }

  public static MemberExpression GetProperty<T>(ParameterExpression linqParam, string propertyName)
  {
      List<string> propertyNames = propertyName.Split('.').ToList();

      var linqProp = Expression.Property(linqParam, propertyNames[0]);

      for (int i = 1; i < propertyNames.Count(); i++)
      {
          linqProp = Expression.Property(linqProp, propertyNames[i]);
      }

      return linqProp;
  }
```

}

and you would call it like:

```
returnQuery = returnQuery.Like("ID", doubleValue);
```